# Rails parse link into HTML button

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-4, button

how can I parse the @product.link from rails into this button? They show up right after each other. How can I get the rails partial into the button part?

```
<input type="button" class="add-to-cart button nomargin"> 
<%= link_to 'External Url', @product.link%>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can't understand what you want. Do you want to make `link_to` look like button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what helped me in the end.. was simpler than thought

Thanks for all your input!

```
<%= link_to "Buy", @product.link, :class => "add-to-cart button nomargin" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a form that is submitted by your button. The form action can point to the relevant resource.

```
<%= form_for @product.link do |f| %>
  <%= button_tag class: 'add-to-cart button nomargin' %>
  <!-- button_tag defaults to type='submit' -->
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks, button looks good but I still have the problem how to include the link.

Comment: You don't need the link. When you click the button, the form gets submitted - since the action of the form is same the href of the link, clicking the button has the same effect as clicking the link would have had.